# ViewController inside Content View issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have this two view controllers:[image]

If i run the app i get this:

[image]

I only see a part of the child view controller.

If i make the container higher, like this:

[image]

I can see it all, but the problem is that i can still scroll it up and down, which also happens in the first case.

[image]

How can i make that inner view controller fixed so that the user cannot scroll inside it?

PS: I am sorry for this bad description, i am not used to iPhone terminology.

LE: Pics describing that scrolling inside the inner container:
Before
[image]

After (holding mouse down on username text field and moving up)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is to do with the constraints in autoLayout.

Select the container view and set height values to a fixed amount ( can be done from bottom right hand corner of storyboard)

[image]

I hope this help, Jim

Updated - Re Scrolling of table within Container View--

If you select the tableView within the ContainerView and go to the attributes, (See example below), you will see there is an option for "Scrolling Enabled". If you uncheck this, your problem should be solved.

Hope it helps. Thanks again, Jim.

[image]

Comment: I pinned the height but still the same result :(

Comment: Now that you've pinned the height of the container, click on the container object and it will show the other blue line constraints, you will need to remove the one that constrains the bottom of the container to the bottom of the whole view controller view. It is currently squashed as the constraints are OK for iPhone 5 screen, but the iPhone 4 screen still listens to the constraints so it'll need some work. It's a bit frustrating but it should be fixed if you remove the blue line constraint from the bottom of container to the bottom of the whole view. hope it helps. Cheers Jim.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the height is set now but the scroll issue still persists. If i hold the mouse on the username text field and i scroll the content of the inner table view controller gets all scroller. What can i do to block this behaviour?. I will update the question by adding two pics.

Comment: @user2611691 I've updated my original answer to include details of the scrolling issue. I hope this does the trick for you. Cheers, Jim.